# Having an HTML body when using the Apple Mail app Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

So I know we can invoke the mail with the following to use HTML:

```
func sendEmail(){
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["example@gmail.com"])
            mail.setSubject("Example Subject")
            mail.setMessageBody("<H1>Test</H1>", isHTML: true)
            present(mail, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

However, I'm looking to add generic sharing functionality using the `UIActivityItemProvider` After implementing the protocol and defining the following method:

```
override func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
            if activityType == .mail {
                return "&lt;body&gt;&lt;H1&gt;testing&lt;/H1&gt;&lt;/body&gt;"
            }   

            return "Other String"

    }
```

But I just get the following in the body of the mail: `<body><H1>testing</H1></body>` instead of the HTML interpretation. Is it even possible to share a string to the mail app such that HTML is rendered?

Comment: I answer your question, can you at least tell me if solves your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use this, for me work just fine

```
override func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
        if activityType == .mail {
            return "<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM><html><head></head><body>Test</body></html>"
        }

        return "Other String"

    }
```

Hope this helps you